# Git fetch/merge on amended commit not working

Tags: git

I have a Git repository on my development folder and another that I use as a stable base for my team to test. Both are on the same machine.

The test folder has development folder as its remote origin. So when I want to publish something for my team to test, I do a

```
git fetch orgin
git merge origin/master
```

from my test folder.

This time I did a commit in the development folder, as usual, fetched and merged in the test folder, and all worked ok.

But then I realized I had left a debug on one of the files, so I removed the debug line, staged, and amended the previous commit on the development folder but when I tried to fetch and merge in the test dir, it showed the following message:

```
user@machine:/opt/testfolder$ git fetch origin
remote: Counting objects: 47, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 25 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (25/25), done.
From /home/user/dev/php/devfolder
 + 4dcc4dd...e48254a master     -> origin/master  (forced update)
user@machine:/opt/testfolder$ git merge origin/master
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
```

And the amended file wasn't updated. If I try again the I get an "Already up-to-date." message.

How can I fix this ? the questions on Stack Overflow on this subject aren't from amended commits. Or at least I couldn't find any. I also couldn't find any documentation on this kind of error from amended commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you are making commits directly in a repo (/home/user/dev/php/devfolder) that is also used as a remote. If that is the case, then the rule of "never rewrite history (i.e. --amend) on commits that have been pushed to the remote" becomes "never rewrite history, period". This is because every commit you do in `/home/user/dev/php/devfolder` can be considered immediately "pushed", since other repos are pulling from it. What happened is that you committed the file with the "debug line" in the dev folder, then pulled into your testfolder. At that point, as far as git is concerned that commit is part of the history. Then when you amended the commit in devfolder, git removed the old commit and replaced it with a new one (without the debug line). Then when you pulled into testfolder again, git sees this as a new commit, which is not a direct descendent of the old one, but a peer of the old one. (You can tell that something is up when you see "forced update" in the fetch message). So git merges both the original commit and the amended commit, and sees the added line in the original commit, so adds it to the result.

While you may be able to fix this up with a series of `git reset`s on both the dev and test folders, if anyone else has pulled from the test folder the offending change will just keep coming back. The best thing to do is make a non-amended commit that removes it. If you intend to do this directly on the dev folder, make sure to pull **from** test into dev first.

Going forward, I would strongly recommend that you create a bare repo in the dev folder, which is intended to be a remote only. Then make all changes in a "local" repo (like you have in your test directory) and push/pull to/from the bare repo.

As an aside, I would probably opt for one bare repo that both you and your team use as a remote, which has both the stable and development code on it, with each being in a different branch, rather than the setup you have now. Then when you want your team to test it, you just merge the dev branch into the stable one.

Comment: Great. That was the point. I made a new commit and I fixed it. Thanks for your advices. I'll try to implement them.